# How can I use pagemap with google custom search refinements?

Tags: google-custom-search

I'm trying to add refinements to my google custom search.
I have meta tags on just about every page of the site, such as

```
<meta name="type-id" content="241" />
```

Where there are many different types, and I want to have one refinement for each type.
In the [docs](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/structured_search#using-filter-by-attribute-with-other-features), it says

> You can also use these more:pagemap: operators with refinement labels

But I have been unable to do that.
Note that I have had success using `more:pagemap:metatags-type-id:241` in the search input, or as a `webSearchQueryAddition` - but despite googles docs, I haven't been able to get it to work with a refinement.

Here's a sample from my cse.xml (removing some attributes from the CustomSearchEngine tag):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomSearchEngine>
  <Title>Test</Title>
  <Context>
    <Facet>
      <FacetItem>
        <Label name="videos" mode="FILTER">
          <Rewrite>more:p:metatags-article-keyword:121</Rewrite>
        </Label>
        <Title>Videos</Title>
      </FacetItem>
    </Facet>
  </Context>
</CustomSearchEngine>
```

Is this supposed to work? Am I using wrong syntax in the rewrite rule? Has anyone else done something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your label in the facet should be mode="BOOST" if you want to restrict to a structured data field within the scope of your engine.

```
<Facet>
   <FacetItem>
      <Label name="videos" mode="BOOST">
          <Rewrite>more:p:metatags-article-keyword:121</Rewrite>
      </Label>
      <Title>Videos</Title>
   </FacetItem>
</Facet>
```

Comment: Thank you! Is that documented somewhere? That structured data can only be used with BOOST? Really, I prefer filter, because I don't want non-matching results, and for a more accurate result count.

Comment: I'm not sure there's good documentation.

You can think of it as:

**BOOST** - search within the entire scope of the engine.
**INCLUDE** - search within only the url patterns that have the given label.

So if you use INCLUDE, but don't have any url patterns for that label, then you are searching within nothing.